# Rotating screen does not save text colour kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, onsaveinstancestate

I have a simple increment app. When you press on the button the number goes up. However i also made the number change to red once it's higher then 5.
I was able to get the number to save on rotation however the colour resets back to normal.
I'm not sure how i can also save the colour. Any ideas on how i can do this?

```
// number starts at 0
var num = 0

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
      
        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)


        val add = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)

        add.setOnClickListener {
            ++num
            if(num > 5) {
                textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"))
            }

            textView.setText(num.toString())
        }
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)

        outState.putInt("int", num)
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            num = savedInstanceState.getInt("int")

            textView.setText(num.toString())
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update this method `onRestoreInstanceState`

```
 override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        num = savedInstanceState.getInt("int")
        if(num > 5){
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"))
        }
        textView.setText(num.toString())
    }

}
```